# identifying a component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I was following **Mosh Hamedani**'s tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=1542s)  for creating **react-app**.

I did exactly what he said.

I'm trying to pass an argument called `product` to a function which is called for `onClick` 
However, I'm getting an error for which I didn't find much info.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  formatCount() {
    return this.state.count === 0 ? "Zero" : this.state.count;
  }

  handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className={this.formatSpan()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
          className="btn btn-primary"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Here's the error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/counter.jsx   Line 41:  'product' is not defined 
>   no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: You never defined a `product` inside the render method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to you because you did not give an input to your function. product is your input variable not input value. If for example ran a code like below, and check your browser console you see that it prints value of `1`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  formatCount() {
    return this.state.count === 0 ? "Zero" : this.state.count;
  }

  handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {

   const product=1;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className={this.formatSpan()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
          className="btn btn-primary"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

I hope it was helpful. Please vote me up if it worked for you:)